# Returning an Int Array from a Custom String Method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a custom method that returns `AnalyzerInts[]` to count lowercase, uppercase, whitespace, punctuation, and character count of `string input`. I am getting an unhandled exception error. "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array." How do I correctly retrieve my `Int[] AnalyzerInts` values into my main method?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string/sentence: ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        int[] answers = StringAnalyzer(userInput);
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} uppercase letters in your string.", answers[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} lowercase letters in your string.", answers[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} whitespace characters in your string.", answers[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} punctuation characters in your string.", answers[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} characters in your string.", answers[4]);
    }





    static int[] StringAnalyzer (string input)
    {
        int[] AnalyzerInts = new int[4];
        for (int x = 0; x < input.Length; x++)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(input[x]))
            {
                AnalyzerInts[0]++;
            }
            else if (char.IsLower(input[x]))
            {
                AnalyzerInts[1]++;
            }
            else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(input[x]))
            {
                AnalyzerInts[2]++;
            }
            else if (char.IsPunctuation(input[x]))
            {
                AnalyzerInts[3]++;
            }
            AnalyzerInts[4]++;
        }
        return AnalyzerInts;
    }
```

Comment: It throws an error becasue you declare the function as returning a `string` but try to return an `int[]`.  Change the return type to `int[]` if that's what the function should return.

Comment: Does that even compile?  I've never seen code that looks like `return AnalyzerInts[];`, nor would I expect to.

Comment: It didn't compile until I correctly changed my method signature to `static int[] StringAnalyzer (string input)`. Now I am just trying to correctly return my `AnalyzerInts;` value to my main method without getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method definition can be viewed as `[return type] [method name] ([parameters])`
In your case, you defined `StringAnalyzer` to receive a `string` parameter named `input` and *return* a `string` value (that's indicated by `string` before the method name)

What you're looking for is to have the method accept a `string` but return an array of integers `int[]`, so the method should be defined as

```
static int[] StringAnalyzer(string input) { /*...*/}
```

Also, when returning, you don't need the `[]`, you only need `return AnalyzerInts`

Finally, you need to initialize your array to contain 5 elements not 4: `int[] AnalyzerInts = new int[5];`

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Now I am attempting to correctly retrieve the return value `AnalyzerInts;` to my main method. See the edit.

Comment: See edit to answer, the problem might be because your array was initialized with 4 elements only but you're using 5

Comment: I see. `Int[] name = new int[number of elements]`when declaring the new variable. But `name[0]` when calling the first element. So the index of 0 only is used when calling the elements, not when declaring the array. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. When declaring the array, you specify the *number of elements*, in your case 5. When *indexing* (accessing/calling) the array, the first index starts at 0, so for an array with size 5, indexing goes 0,1,2,3, and 4

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a major help.

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is `string` and you are trying to return an `int[]`.

Change your method signature to:

```
static int[] StringAnalyzer (string input)
```

and change your return statement to:

```
return AnalyzerInts;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
int[] AnalyzerInts = new int[4];
```

to:

```
int[] AnalyzerInts = new int[5];
```

Because if you look at your code, you will see that your array is assumed to have 5 items, not 4. (Hint: You're printing 5 sentences to the console, and the highest index you're accessing is 4. C# arrays start at index 0.)